# Extension of an Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm really stucked in this problem

Let $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $A:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ an Isometry. Show that $A$ can be extended to an Isometry in all $\mathbb{R}^3$ that's fix the origin.

I try using $\hat{A}=A/(|x-y|)$ Assuming that $A$ is linear, can I show that $\hat{A}$ is linear to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try $\hat A(\vec{w})= |\vec w|A(\vec w/|\vec w|)$.